# Can this custom SCSS grid be simplified?

Tags: sass, grid

I wrote this SCSS grid. There is also a js variable that sets the maximum number of items per row, (min=4, max=8). With that variable I add a class to the grid wrapper and get different CSS.

As you can see in the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/fy5kw84v/), it works fine, but it feel like it unnecessarily complicated. Is there a more elegant way to write this SCSS?

```
.grid-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  margin: 0 -10px;

  .grid-item,
  .grid-orphan {
    margin: 20px 10px 0;
    align-self: stretch;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 1px;
    background-color: #0000CC;
    height: 50px;

  }

  .grid-orphan {
    height: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  /*

  EIGHT


  */
  &.eight {

    // eight
    @media screen and (min-width: 2201px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(12.5% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // seven
    @media screen and (min-width: 2021px) and (max-width: 2200px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 7) - 20px);

      }
    }

    // six
    @media screen and (min-width: 1827px) and (max-width: 2020px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 6) - 20px);

      }
    }

    // five
    @media screen and (min-width: 1527px) and (max-width: 1826px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(20% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // four
    @media screen and (min-width: 1277px) and (max-width: 1526px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(25% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // three
    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1276px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // two
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      justify-content: space-between;

      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
      }
    }
  }

  /*

  SEVEN


  */
  &.seven {

    // seven
    @media screen and (min-width: 2021px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 7) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // six
    @media screen and (min-width: 1827px) and (max-width: 2020px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 6) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // five
    @media screen and (min-width: 1527px) and (max-width: 1826px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(20% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // four
    @media screen and (min-width: 1277px) and (max-width: 1526px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(25% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // three
    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1276px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // two
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      justify-content: space-between;

      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
      }
    }
  }

  /*

  SIX


  */
  &.six {

    // six
    @media screen and (min-width: 1827px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 6) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // five
    @media screen and (min-width: 1527px) and (max-width: 1826px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(20% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // four
    @media screen and (min-width: 1277px) and (max-width: 1526px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(25% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // three
    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1276px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // two
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      justify-content: space-between;

      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
      }
    }
  }

  /*

  FIVE


  */
  &.five {

    // five
    @media screen and (min-width: 1527px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(20% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // four
    @media screen and (min-width: 1277px) and (max-width: 1526px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(25% - 20px);
      }
    }

    // three
    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1276px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // two
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      justify-content: space-between;

      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
      }
    }
  }

  /*

  FOUR


  */
  &.four {

    // four
    @media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(25% - 20px);
      }

    }

    // three
    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1599px) {
      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
      }
    }

    // two
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
      justify-content: space-between;

      .grid-item {
        min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
      }
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 600px) {
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

    .grid-item {
      min-width: 100%;
      margin: 20px 0 0;

      &:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
    }

    .grid-orphan {
      min-width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straight forward suggestion to solving your layout using [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

I made an opinionated change going from the smallest screens and up, so that it's easier to only use `min-width` in your media queries.

If you don't *need* to have different column setups based on the helper classes, you could even just remove all media queries and let the rules for 8 columns apply for all cases.

**Edit:**

Here is a simplified (oh the irony) attempt:

```
.grid-wrap {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;

    .grid-item,
    .grid-orphan {
        background-color: #0000cc;
        height: 50px;
    }

    // Breakpoints are initially the same in all columns variations
    @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1277px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1527px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1827px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 2021px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 2201px) {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    }

    &.four {
        // Different breakpoint values in 4 column variations
        @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        }
    }

    &.five {
        // No overrides
    }

    &.six {
        // No overrides
    }

    &.seven {
        // No overrides
    }

    &.eight {
        // No overrides
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up converting my flex container to grid. It's a fairly massive site with dozens of grids on dozens of different pages with different implementations, so I was afraid to refactor it, but seeing your example encouraged me to try and it was easy peasy. The only change was I added some mixins for the breakpoints and I had to add a minmax, so: `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(0, 1fr));`

Comment: That sounds like a clever solution, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You could start by having some mixins for the ones you have more than once to keep things DRY.

e.g.

```
// two
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  justify-content: space-between;

  .grid-item {
    min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
}
```

becomes:

```
@mixin two {
  @media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    justify-content: space-between;

    .grid-item {
      min-width: calc(50% - 20px);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in all the places where you have the first code block above just add:

```
@include two;
```

Best to assign your magic numbers to sass vars too, it'll read a lot nicer. You could potentially get some maps and loops involved but it shouldn't really need it.

Comment: thank you. I may use some mixins, but the at media min / max widths may change such that I may have to code it. I would use a sass var for the max--per-row count  but the client wants to be able to change it in one place and not have to compile anything. :(

Comment: I see, will have another think today. Please upvote if you think that could help others. Cheers!